# Command line connection to documentdb when rotating password

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-documentdb

I'm using documentdb with the password being automatically rotated via aws secret manager.  I want to script up a fast way to connect to the database via command line.  Since the password changes frequently that means having a command that will load the password from aws secerts and pass it to the mongo connect string.  I had come up with this hideous one liner to connect to mongo:

```
mongo --ssl --host *my_host*:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username admin --password `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id documentDB_login | jq .SecretString | jq fromjson | jq .password`
```

I had already run aws configure and secretmanager does return my password correctly.

I swear this worked at first, but it is now failing, saying authentication failed when it tries to connect to my mongo instance.  If I echo the above ugly one liner, so that i can see the result of the aws secretmanager call, and then copy and paste the echo response into my commandline it connects correctly, so not sure why the functionally equivalent command does not.

How can I script up an easy way to connect to to documentdb via commandline? Is there a cleaner approach (preferably one that doesn't require yum install of jp) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say for sure why your command was working before but does not now, but it looks like it is not stripping double quotes. Also the AWS cli can do JSON parsing for you, but unfortunately, it can not parse the nested JSON in the secret itself. For that you will still need jq. However, combining the CLI JSON parsing with jq you could simplify it a bit (though it is no shorter):

```
mongo --ssl --host *my_host*:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username admin --password `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id documentDB_login --query 'SecretString' --output text | jq -r .password`
```